# Locking the user screen in Windows store apps for Windows Surface

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, locking, screen

I am developing an application for Windows Surface RT.I have an requirement to lock the device screen
programmatically(thru c#). I searched MSDN and various form but in vain. Please help me to figure out this requirement.

Comment: what do you mean by "locking screen"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't force the screen to be "locked" from a Windows Store application. It's just not an available API.